# How to see discount price only the product page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3, discount, opencart-module

I have an extension. Customer discount.  I want to see the discounted product price at the cart and at the bill. How can I do it?
[see what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP2Qg.png)

```
<?php
class ModelExtensionTotalCustomerDiscount extends Model {
    public function getTotal($total) {


        if ($this->cart->getSubTotal() > 0) {

            $this->load->language('extension/total/customer_discount');

           $price = 0;
            $special->row['discount'] = 0;

            if(isset($this->session->data['customer_id']) && $this->session->data['customer_id'] > 0) {
                $special = $this->db->query("SELECT discount FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_id = '".(int)$this->session->data['customer_id']."'");

                if(isset($special->row['discount']) && $special->row['discount'] > 0) {

                    $price = ($special->row['discount'] / 100) * $this->cart->getSubTotal();


                }
            }
            if ($price > 0) {
                $total['totals'][] = array(
                    'code'       => 'customer_discount',
                    'title'      => sprintf($this->language->get('text_discount'),$special->row['discount'].'%'),
                    'value'      => - $price,
                    'sort_order' => $this->config->get('total_customer_discount_sort_order')
                );

                $total['total'] -= $price;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You were upload cart page screenshot?

Comment: opencart already gives functionality for the discount price shown on the product page. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Zs3-KdG_-bUP5wtTF6wNuF0Jt2KUQA_j/view?usp=sharing